# Android Studio to 3.0 - Unable to merge dex[DexArchiveMergerException]

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have project and I added another project as module and I have big problem with this error message:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
> >     dex

I tried many solutions in stackoverflow and google but i don't found an answer.

For example:

1. I try added to defaultConfig multiDexEnabled true.
2. I try to clean and rebuild.
3. I try to Invalidate catch/Restart and then rebuild.

My project gradle:

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

My app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "adms.foxitpdf"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/FoxitRDK.jar')
    compile project(path: ':uiextensions_src')
}
```

And my module gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions{
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation files('src/libs/FoxitRDK.jar')
}

task clearAar(type: Delete){
    delete '../FoxitRDKUIExtensions.aar'
}

task makeAar(type: Exec){
    dependsOn(clearAar,build)
    def fromFile = 'build/outputs/aar/'
    def intoFile = '../'
    if(org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().windows) {
        commandLine "cmd",
                '-/C', 'copy', file("$fromFile/uiextensions_src-release.aar").absolutePath, file("$intoFile/FoxitRDKUIExtensions.aar")
    }else {
        commandLine "cp",
                file("$fromFile/uiextensions_src-release.aar").absolutePath, file("$intoFile/FoxitRDKUIExtensions.aar")
    }
}
makeAar {}.dependsOn(clearAar,build)

task makeJavaDoc(type: Javadoc) {
    List<String> mSourcePath = new ArrayList<String>();
    mSourcePath.add("../../fsdk/app/src/main/java/com/foxit/sdk/");
    mSourcePath.add("src/main/java/com/foxit/uiextensions/UIExtensionsManager.java");
    mSourcePath.add("src/main/java/com/foxit/uiextensions/Module.java");
    mSourcePath.add("src/main/java/com/foxit/uiextensions/pdfreader/impl/PDFReader.java");
    mSourcePath.add("src/main/java/com/foxit/uiextensions/controls/menu/IMenuView.java");
    mSourcePath.add("src/main/java/com/foxit/uiextensions/controls/menu/MoreMenuConfig.java");
    mSourcePath.add("src/main/java/com/foxit/uiextensions/controls/menu/MoreMenuModule.java");
    mSourcePath.add("src/main/java/com/foxit/uiextensions/controls/toolbar/IBaseItem.java");
    mSourcePath.add("src/main/java/com/foxit/uiextensions/controls/toolbar/IBarsHandler.java");
    mSourcePath.add("src/main/java/com/foxit/uiextensions/controls/propertybar/IMultiLineBar.java");

    source = mSourcePath;
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    InputStream inputStream = project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream() ;
    properties.load( inputStream )
    //读取文件
    def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
    ext.androidJar = sdkDir + "/extras/android/support/annotations/android-support-annotations.jar"
    classpath += project.files(ext.androidJar)

    destinationDir = file("../../docs/api_reference_android")
    failOnError false
}

makeJavaDoc {
    options {
        encoding "UTF-8"
        charSet 'UTF-8'
        author true
        version true
        memberLevel = org.gradle.external.javadoc.JavadocMemberLevel.PUBLIC
        locale = "en"
        title = "Document of RDK for Android"

        // fsdk overview
        Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> fsdkOverViews= new ArrayList<>();
        fsdkOverViews.add("com.foxit.sdk");
        fsdkOverViews.add("com.foxit.sdk.*");
        map.put("Fsdk Packages",fsdkOverViews);

        // UIExtensions overview
        List<String> uiExtendOverViews = new ArrayList<>();
        uiExtendOverViews.add("com.foxit.uiextensions");
        uiExtendOverViews.add("com.foxit.uiextensions.*");
        map.put("UIExtenstions Packages",uiExtendOverViews);

        groups = map;
    }
}
```

I use with **Android Studio to 3.0**

Someone have idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to include this below one to your gradle as well as add **dependencies** and include in **manifest** also. If you have enabled only in **gradle** and does not include in manifest and dependencies then give it a shot.

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

add to your dependencies

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "adms.foxitpdf"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true //Add this
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on how you override Application add this to your manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

or we can just do like this and again include in manifest with name tag.

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

Read full story [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)